# Wayland create window requesting it be centered?

Tags: c++, c, linux, wayland

So I know setting a Wayland Window position isn't supported.
However can I create a Window requesting the server create it centered? Are there any hints or anything for this both Gnome and KDE might respect?

WinRT for example I can request the window center screen without being able to set the Window position directly.

Also does Wayland support detecting if client or server side decorations are available?

Comment: What C++ library are you using?

Comment: Regarding decorations, there is the `xdg-decoration-unstable-v1` protocol, which supports server-side decorations (also switching between client- and server-side).

Comment: @stark Just native Wayland client libraries. (not GTK or QT). I'm trying to match some Window creation code I have for Win32 & Cocoa in native Wayland.